# data not getting displayed in datagridview

Tags: winforms

i am currently working on importing data from excel sheet to sql server.i have written a code for removing empty rows from the excel sheet..now i am trying to see the data in datagridview by assigning the method name to the datagridview datasource..but it is not displaying any data.Can anyone say me if i am doing correct or wrong. This is my code..

```
   public partial class Form9 : Form
{
    DataSet dsExcel = new DataSet();

    public Form9()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //String input = string.Empty;
        OpenFileDialog filepath = new OpenFileDialog();
        filepath.Filter = "Excel Files(*.xls)|*.xls|Excel Files(*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|Text Files(*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
        filepath.InitialDirectory = "C:";
        filepath.Title = "Select a file";
        if (filepath.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            txtExcelFile.Text = filepath.FileName;
        if (txtExcelFile.Text == string.Empty)
            return;
    }

    private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        OleDbConnection cnn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + txtExcelFile.Text + "';Extended Properties= 'Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'");
        cnn.Open();
        try
        {

            OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Customers$]", cnn);

            data.Fill(dsExcel);

            dgvCustomers.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
            dgvCustomers.DataSource = GetExcelData();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //cnn.Close();
        }

    }

       public DataSet GetExcelData()
        {
        DataTable ExcelTable = new DataTable();
        List<int> rowToRemove = new List<int>();
        //DataRow ExcelRow = new DataRow();

        foreach (DataRow excelrow in dsExcel.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            bool IsEmpty = false;
            foreach (object item in excelrow.ItemArray)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(item.ToString())) 
                {
                     IsEmpty = true;
                     break;

                }                  
                else
                {
                    IsEmpty = false;

                }
            }
            if (IsEmpty)
            { 
                rowToRemove.Add((dsExcel.Tables[0].Rows.IndexOf(excelrow)));
            }

        }

        for (int i = rowToRemove.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            dsExcel.Tables[0].Rows.RemoveAt(rowToRemove[i]);

        }
        return dsExcel;

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your datasource should be a datatable in the dataset, not the dataset itself.

Change

```
public DataSet GetExcelData()
```

to

```
public DataTable GetExcelData()
```

and at the end, return this:

```
return dsExcel.Tables[0];
```

Comment: thanks it worked..but i have one doubt..i have seen in few examples that the datagridview datasource is Dataset.I want to know why we are assigning datatable here and not dataset..i am new in coding..starting from scratch..

Comment: @Nazima Think of a dataset as a database-- it can hold more than one datatable.